# Trying to remove elements in an array : Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, list, data-structures

I'm working on a Codewar challenge in Ruby to remove elements from a array of strings. So far I have tried using the `Array.delete_at(Array.index(value))` which is meant to remove the first occurrence of a repeating value from the array however that did not work. I believe I may need to combine that with something else but not sure what.

these are what my tests currently look like when I run them:

```
Expected: ["Hello", "Hello Again"], instead got: ["Hello"]
Expected: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], instead got: [1]
Test Passed: Value == [[1, 2]]
Test Passed: Value == [["Goodbye"]]
Test Passed: Value == []
```

so far I'm using the `.shift` method, and that seems to have done half the job. any suggestions on how I can target the whole substring.

```
def remove_every_other(arr)
  arr.shift(1) 
end
```

for more clarification please find the practise tests and link to the Kata below:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/5769b3802ae6f8e4890009d2/train/ruby

```
Test.describe("Basic tests") do
  Test.assert_equals(remove_every_other(['Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Hello Again']),['Hello', 'Hello Again'])
  Test.assert_equals(remove_every_other([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]),[1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
  Test.assert_equals(remove_every_other([[1, 2]]), [[1, 2]])
  Test.assert_equals(remove_every_other([['Goodbye'], {'Great': 'Job'}]), [['Goodbye']])
  Test.assert_equals(remove_every_other([]), [])
end
```

Comment: Array of strings* I've added a link to the kata challenge.

Comment: `arr.each_with_index.select {|i,v| v % 2 == 0 }.map(&:first)` might work? Did not test the cases, but tested with `(1..20).to_a`. Not the prettiest solution, though.

Comment: It works, thanks mate. You should add to answers and if you could add a little explanation on how it works that will be superb!

Comment: @FrederikSpang `v.odd?` or `v.even?` are good tools here.

Comment: @FrederikSpang, you don't need `.map(&:first)` if you write `arr.select!.with_index { |_,i| i.even? }`. Note the question calls for `arr` is to be mutated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a ton of tools in [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html) that make this trivial:

```
a = %w[ a b c d e f ]

a.each_slice(2).map(&:first)
# => ["a", "c", "e"]
```

Where that first carves up the array into pairs, then takes the first of each pair.

The problem with your `shift` approach is it does one operation, it doesn't iterate. You *must* work through the whole array to make this happen.

Now you could use a combination of `shift` and an accumulator, but it's generally bad form to consume the array you're given when a more *functional* version exists. `each_slice` produces a new result, it doesn't alter the original, making it easier to coordinate in more complex code where that input value might be shared.

Answer (score 1):

multiple solutions possible. But - don't forget that you do not need to remove elements to solve this challenge - your method needs to return proper values that's all. So following code should also work:

```
   arr.select{ |e| arr.find_index(e).even? }
```

Comment: This code will very likely fail if array contains duplicate elements

Comment: Yeah - but the task in this challenge is: 'Take an array and remove every second element from the array. Always keep the first element and start removing with the next element.'  ;)

Comment: Yes, and this code will fail to do so on an array like `[1,1,1,1,1]`